# Anime where a girl with a flute turns students into monsters

Tags: story-identification, anime

There is this anime in which at the first episode at the mc's school, the students would be turned into monsters, because of a girl (using a flute I believe) which was together with a other guy. What's the name of the anime?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You might be able to improve this question by checking out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for story-id and [anime-id](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/101407) question.

Comment: What did the characters look like?  Hair type,  color...?  How old did it look or when did you watch it?

Answer (score 1):

Could be Blood: The Last Vampire or its spin-off, Blood+

The girl in question could be the antagonist (Diva) who is an excellent singer and I believe it might be her minion who plays the flute.

Other details: One of the protagonist characters (Saya) appears to be school aged and goes to a school and the anime starts in a school setting.

Story features people turning to monsters at least partly in response to music.

There might be more details on the [Blood+ Wiki](https://bloodplusanime.fandom.com/wiki/Blood%2B_Wiki) to see if anything jogs your memory.